# How to pass function return value to make command in VIM

Tags: vimrc

I have this configuration in .vimrc

```
function! FindProjectRootDir()
      return "some path"
endfunction

set makeprg=LC_ALL=C\ make\ MONOCHROME=1
nnoremap <F7> :make -C FindProjectRootDir()<CR>:copen<CR>
```

when i hit F7, there is a problem, make cannot get parameter from the function FindProjectRootDir()

Comment: I appreciate a response instead of setting -1 for the question, i googled for an answer for hours without success

Comment: You should include `-C ...` in `makeprg` and set it with `exec`: `exec 'set makeprg+=\ -C\ '.FindProjectRootDir()`. I think the -1 is because your question is a little too specific?

Comment: @perelo not the downvoter but the downvote is likely because this question has been asked/answered several times

Answer (score 5):

You should use [`:execute`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute) to run a command built from a string.

For your particular case, this should work:

```
nnoremap <F7> :execute 'make -C '.FindProjectRootDir()<CR>:copen<CR>
```

If it wasn't for `:execute`, Vim would assume what you wanted was the literal `FindProjectRootDir()`.

The ["Execute"](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/28.html) section in "Learn Vimscript the Hard Way" has a great explanation of when you need to use `:execute`, why you need it and why it isn't as dangerous as it may seem (even though it looks a lot like `eval` statements from other languages.)

Comment: Filbranden, appreciate the good-faith effort to answer these questions, but it is actually more helpful to the community long-term to find the duplicate and close this QA to point back to that one. If you feel you can add information, then you can answer/edit what becomes the canonical reference of execute questions. (I’m still hunting down the best one i can find; for now ive voted to close this one as a dupe of the other one you recently answered.)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Ah yes great point! This one surely has a duplicate. I'll flag is as well. (Next election cycle, you get my vote for moderator here too!)

Comment: thanks! Means a lot 